# I have PDF file which contains SVG images , but it can not print via IE browser , browser crash

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, printing

I have PDF file which contains **SVG** images , but it can not proper print via **IE browser.** 
- If file is large then **browser crash**. It take much memory.
- I can not found any Converter which convert this SVG content into PNG within same pdf file.
- I am using java code for Print functionality.

Comment: Why is this question related to java?

Comment: For Print functionality i used java code. Printing working fine in Chrome but can not print in IE-11

Comment: Have you wrote an applet?

Comment: No not Applet used in it.

Comment: Hi, PDF files are rendered and printed from ActiveX Applications (eg. Adobe PDF Reader) inside a browser frame..... your problem lies with the PDF document reader application/addon that you have installed, or your physical printers drivers... see Start>Control Panel>Administrative tools>Event viewer to find the crash report for IE (it should have logged an error report for the crashing print process)...or your IE version or PDF application is not up to date. Check your PDF viewer addons vendors site for updates for their products.